# How to stop two orchard modules conflicting

Tags: orchardcms, autofac, orchard-modules

I have two Orchard Modules.

Both have implementations of `IAppSettings` , which is defined in an external dll, and referenced in  the modules via nuget package (So I cannot use `IDependency` ).

I wire these up using an Autofac Module class in each module.

Unfortunately this leads to "last registration wins" and both modules will use the last registered implementation, even though the "expected" result would be that each uses their own.

To be clear, each module is developed by a separate team, who don't co-ordinate with each other, but do use the same guidelines for module creation. The example above is just one instance of this occurring, but it is fair to assume there would be more.

How might I go about ensuring that each team can register their own dependencies for their modules, without constantly having to check with the authors of other modules?

Comment: Update: The best I have been able to manage is to use autofac's named registrations. For example in module B

builder.Register(c => new AppSettings("ModuleB")).Named<IAppSettings>("ModuleB").SingleInstance();

and in a consumer

public ModuleBController(ILifetimeScope scope)
        {
            _provider = scope.ResolveNamed<IAppSettings>("ModuleB");
        }

It doesn't feel great because there is more awareness needed of the possibility of conflict.

Answer (score 1):

There is one Autofac container per tenant, not per (Orchard) modules. You see the implications of this.

However this couldn't be much differently since interaction between modules would be seriously hindered if dependencies would be scoped to extensions.

Also one of the points of DI is that you can override the implementation: this is also desired here, since if you implement a dependency in Module A, then also in Module B (where Module B depends on Module A) then Module B can override the default implementation. This is a good thing.

Instead of wanting to require specific implementations for your interfaces what kind of defeats DI you could implement the strategy pattern for example. But if you tell more details I could help more.

Comment: What he said: if you need a specific implementation of an interface, there's a very well known mechanism for that, and it's not dependency injection, it's "new".

Comment: Using "new" is not enterprise-y. At least use a factory! :-D

Comment: Developer A is unaware of developer B, and both are equally likely to want an interface in their controllers, and then wire up registrations in autofac (since in this particular area we cannot use IDependency).

I understand why what is "is" - I'm asking for any suggestions on how to provide clear guidance when developing to avoid inadvertently overriding another modules code, when that was not the intent. The best I've been able to We have 7 different teams managing isolated modules that will be deployed into one orchard host. The best I've got is named registrations so far.

Comment: And are you confident that you need DI for this for the sake of e.g. being able to still switch the implementation? You could use a factory too (an IDependency factory that returns an IAppSettings, where the implementation is a simple instantiation), per module: (IAModuleAppSettingsFactory, IBModuleAppSettingsFactory...). And again, you could use the strategy pattern and have a method that returns the necessary implementation out of an injected IEnumerable<IAppSettings>.